# mysql remove points from the E-mail Addresses

Tags: mysql, regex

I have few gmail addresses in my table

```
foobarbaz@gmail.com 
foo.bar.baz@gmail.com
foobar.baz@gmail.com
foo.barbaz@gmail.com
```

I need to replace addresses gmail that contain the symbol '.' 
to get:

```
foobarbaz@gmail.com 
foobarbaz@gmail.com
foobarbaz@gmail.com
foobarbaz@gmail.com
```

my query does not work

```
UPDATE voters set email
replace(substring(email, 1, LOCATE('@', email) -1), '.', '')
WHERE email REGEXP '@googlemail.com|@gmail.com'
```

please help, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extracting the substring before the `@` and replacing the dots, but you're not adding back the substring after the `@` after you do this:

```
UPDATE voters 
SET email = CONCAT(replace(substring(email, 1, LOCATE('@', email) -1), '.', ''),
                   SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email)))
WHERE email REGEXP '@googlemail.com|@gmail.com'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c937/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar as the following query using [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) & [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
UPDATE table1
SET email = CONCAT (
        replace(substring_index(email, '@', 1), '.', '')
        ,substring(email, instr(email, '@'))
        )
WHERE substring_index(email, '@', -1) IN (
        'googlemail.com'
        ,'gmail.com'
        );
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd5b043/1)